# How to use SPI with DFRobot Beetle ESP32?

Tags: microcontroller, esp32, spi

Does anyone know if the Beetle ESP32 can communicate via SPI? I saw a project for a tutorial on SPI connection [here](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/A1VO7RyKHzL.pdf), but it only mentions FireBeetle ESP32.

Comment: Read Page 35 regarding SPI.

Comment: @hcheung Thank you for the reply. That's actually the project I was referring to, but it only mentions SPI of FireBeetle ESP32. What I wanted to know is if that also works for Beetle ESP32 (they are two different microcontrollers) 

[Beetle ESP32]: wiki.dfrobot.com/Beetle_ESP32_SKU_DFR0575

Comment: You will notice that the SPI pins are not break-out on the Beetle if you look at the schematic on the Beetle URL that you provided.